# how to send multiple values from angular2 form to nodejs server and query from mongodb on the basis of 6 different values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, angular2-forms

I am working in **angular 2** with back end **nodejs** with **express**. I am facing a problem that I have to send a form data to **nodejs server** and then find data from mongoDB database and get the response! Help me please. I can send only one value id but I have to search on the basis of different values. I don't know the id.

```
router.get('/task/:id', function(req, res, next){

var team = req.params.team;
var opposite = req.params.opposite;
var toss = req.params.toss;
var decision= req.params.decision;
var match = req.params.match;
var ground = req.params.ground;
var query = {};
query[team] = team;
query[Oteam] = Oteam;
query[TossWinner] = TossWinner;
query[Decision] = Decision;
query[Match] = Match;
query[NG] = NG;

    db.pendingPredictions.findOne(query,function(err, pendingPrediction){

        if(err)
            {
                res.send(err);
            }
        else {
            res.json(pendingPrediction);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could clean up your problem description a little bit and perhaps add more detail.

Comment: bro i want you write code for this flow please like i have a form in angular2 form data is used for searching in data and getting response back, form data is sent to the nodejs server that is then connect to mongo but problem i am facing i am sending post request and i want you get my post request variables inside that function, i did change it to from get to post